# Flip part of html5 canvas in javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have a html5 canvas element which has been drawn on.  I now need to flip a rectangular part of this canvas horizontally.

I have tried copying the selected area to a temporary canvas.  I now need code to flip this temporary canvas and then copy it back to the main canvas. This is my code:

```
function swapRow(row) {
    var tempCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    tempCanvas.id     = "tempCanvas";
    tempCanvas.width  = 384;
    tempCanvas.height = 32;
    var tempContext = tempCanvas.getContext('2d');
    var tempImage = context.getImageData(0, 0, 384, 32);
    tempContext.putImageData(tempImage, 0, 0);

    //need code to flip tempContext
        
    tempImage = tempContext.getImageData(0, 0, 384, 32);
    context.putImageData(tempImage, 0, 0);
}
```

The row parameter will be used to decide which rectangular area to flip, I've omitted this logic for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this.

I was trying to flip my temporary canvas, but what I needed to do was get the image from the temporary canvas, set my scaling options and paste the image back on to the temporary canvas. I used toDataURL to get the image from the canvas.

```
function swapRow(row) {
var tempCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
tempCanvas.id     = "tempCanvas";
tempCanvas.width  = 384;
tempCanvas.height = 384 / width;
var tempContext = tempCanvas.getContext('2d');
var tempImage = context.getImageData(30, 30 + (row * tempCanvas.height), 384, tempCanvas.height);
tempContext.putImageData(tempImage, 0, 0);
    
var myImage = new Image();
myImage.src = tempCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
tempContext.scale(-1, 1);
tempContext.drawImage(myImage, -383, 0, 384, tempCanvas.height);
    
tempImage = tempContext.getImageData(0, 0, 384, tempCanvas.height);
context.putImageData(tempImage, 30, 30 + (row * tempCanvas.height));
```

}